# div or iframe over an applet

Tags: javascript, html, css, applet, multimedia

I want to create a custom video control, I mean over the video itself, with issues like double click on some x and y coordinates of the video to zoom In, but I can't get this result because the real player plugin API is not that flexible, then I Tried to create a transparent layer to handle those events and I can't achieve that the transparent layer sits on top of the video, I tried this list:

1.- Put a flash transparent movie over the real player plugin- not working the player breaks the z-Index and the video goes to the top.

2.- Put an Iframe transparent over the real player plugin- not working  it puts on top, but when I make the Iframe transparent, the movie goes agains to the top.

3.- I tried to use the map html tag, also is not working.

4.-I tried to put and div absolute positioned, but z-index is not working.

I need some help with this topic.

thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way to force a browser to layer content on top of a plugin, because plugins like Flash just talk to the video/audio system rather directly and just paint in the bounding box the browser tells them to.

Obviously it's still experimental, and there's no IE support (without ChromeFrame), but  was designed to solve exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this was Flash you could use wmode=opaque or wmode=transparent as an alternative to the default wmode=windowed, which is much faster but causes problems with overlays like you describe. I've found no sign of an equivalent option for real player.

Answer (score 0):

http://javafx.com/ would be my recommendation

I would avoid trying to mash several different technologies together to get what you want, It will make for a maintenance nightmare between different browsers and browser upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you search for:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showpost.php?s=4cc8a233f39321ad1ee9e01ec57a3bef&p=200817&postcount=10

You need the wmode = opaque to get the layer over the flash.
a place where you can find this working is, [www.dtele.de](http://www.dtele.de) .
If you open the navigation, you´ll see, tha it lays over the flash movie.